# getting substring from ustring

Tags: c++, glib, gtkmm

I have a ustring object sourceString which is πøˆ∑´®. These string i get from an XML file while parsing it.I have used substr method to get these character string as under.

```
Glib::ustring uString = sourceString.substr(5,0);
```

But, i could get only null string, how should i a substring from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about how `substr()` is implemented in your case, however I'd hazard that the order of your parameters is wrong! `std::string::substr()` takes position first, and then size. In your case size is 0.

Comment: [Here's the reference](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glibmm/unstable/classGlib_1_1ustring.html#aa20ce59c438020d4bfb29348ba572a30), it shows two arguments, `i` and `n`, which usually denote *index* and *length*.